Ansible regex_replace on values of specific keys in a list of dict
I've been struggling with this for a while. I have a list of dict like this which is created by parsing the Cisco CLI output with neighbors_raw.stdout[0] | ansible.netcommon.parse_cli_textfsm('templates/cisco_ios_show_cdp_neighbors.textfsm'):
[
        {
            "CAPABILITY": "R S I",
            "LOCAL_INTERFACE": "Ten 1/1/1",
            "NEIGHBOR": "switch1.mydomain.com",
            "NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE": "Ten 1/0/4",
            "PLATFORM": "C9500-16X"
        },
        {
            "CAPABILITY": "S I",
            "LOCAL_INTERFACE": "Gig 1/1/2",
            "NEIGHBOR": "switch2.mydomain.com",
            "NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE": "Ten 1/1/1",
            "PLATFORM": "C9200L-48"
        }
]

I want to convert the interface names from Ten 1/1/1 to Te1/1/1 or Gig 1/1/2 to Gi1/1/2.
I have tried the following:
- name: PARSE NEIGHBORS
  debug:
    msg: "{{ neighbors_raw.stdout[0] | ansible.netcommon.parse_cli_textfsm('templates/cisco_ios_show_cdp_neighbors.textfsm') |
      regex_replace('Ten ', 'Te') |
      regex_replace('Gig ', 'Gi') }}"

The output looks correct:
[
        {
            "CAPABILITY": "R S I",
            "LOCAL_INTERFACE": "Te1/1/1",
            "NEIGHBOR": "switch1.mydomain.com",
            "NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE": "Te1/0/4",
            "PLATFORM": "C9500-16X"
        },
        {
            "CAPABILITY": "S I",
            "LOCAL_INTERFACE": "Gi1/1/2",
            "NEIGHBOR": "switch2.mydomain.com",
            "NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE": "Te1/1/1",
            "PLATFORM": "C9200L-48"
        }
]

However, if I pipe this output into any other command it treats it like it is a character array:
- name: PARSE NEIGHBORS
  debug:
    msg: "{{ neighbors_raw.stdout[0] | ansible.netcommon.parse_cli_textfsm('templates/cisco_ios_show_cdp_neighbors.textfsm') |
      regex_replace('Ten ', 'Te') |
      regex_replace('Gig ', 'Gi') | list }}"

Output:
[
        "[",
        "{",
        "'",
        "N",
        "E",
        "I",
        "G",
        "H",
        "B",
        "O",
        "R",
        "'",
        ":",
        " ",
        "'",

The same weird output happens if I use zip instead of list.
I have also tried map('regex_replace', 'Ten (.*)', 'Te\\1') but it only replaces one occurrence and turns each dict in to a string:
- name: PARSE NEIGHBORS
  debug:
    msg: "{{ neighbors_raw.stdout[0] | ansible.netcommon.parse_cli_textfsm('templates/cisco_ios_show_cdp_neighbors.textfsm') |
      map('regex_replace', 'Ten (.*)', 'Te\\1') }}"

Output:
[
        "{'NEIGHBOR': 'switch1.mydomain.com', 'LOCAL_INTERFACE': 'Te1/1/1', 'CAPABILITY': 'R S I', 'PLATFORM': 'C9500-16X', 'NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE': 'Ten 1/0/4'}",
        "{'NEIGHBOR': 'switch2.mydomain.com', 'LOCAL_INTERFACE': 'Gig 1/1/2', 'CAPABILITY': 'S I', 'PLATFORM': 'C9200L-48', 'NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE': 'Te1/1/1'}"
]

I am also concerned about regex_replace on the entire dict treating it like a string. I really only want to apply the conversion to the specific value for LOCAL_INTERFACE and NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE.
How can I go about achieving this?

Given the data
  neighbors:
    - CAPABILITY: R S I
      LOCAL_INTERFACE: Ten 1/1/1
      NEIGHBOR: switch1.mydomain.com
      NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE: Ten 1/0/4
      PLATFORM: C9500-16X
    - CAPABILITY: S I
      LOCAL_INTERFACE: Gig 1/1/2
      NEIGHBOR: switch2.mydomain.com
      NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE: Ten 1/1/1
      PLATFORM: C9200L-48

Create the lists of the updated attributes
  lifc: "{{ neighbors |
            map(attribute='LOCAL_INTERFACE') |
            map('regex_replace', 'Ten ', 'Te') |
            map('regex_replace', 'Gig ', 'Gi') |
            map('community.general.dict_kv', 'LOCAL_INTERFACE') }}"
  nifc: "{{ neighbors |
            map(attribute='NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE') |
            map('regex_replace', 'Ten ', 'Te') |
            map('regex_replace', 'Gig ', 'Gi') |
            map('community.general.dict_kv', 'NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE') }}"

gives
  lifc:
  - LOCAL_INTERFACE: Te1/1/1
  - LOCAL_INTERFACE: Gi1/1/2

  nifc:
  - NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE: Te1/0/4
  - NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE: Te1/1/1

zip the lists and combine items
  update: "{{ lifc | zip(nifc) | map('combine') }}"

gives
  update:
  - LOCAL_INTERFACE: Te1/1/1
    NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE: Te1/0/4
  - LOCAL_INTERFACE: Gi1/1/2
    NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE: Te1/1/1

zip the update and combine items
  result: "{{ neighbors | zip(update) | map('combine') }}"

gives what you want
  result:
  - CAPABILITY: R S I
    LOCAL_INTERFACE: Te1/1/1
    NEIGHBOR: switch1.mydomain.com
    NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE: Te1/0/4
    PLATFORM: C9500-16X
  - CAPABILITY: S I
    LOCAL_INTERFACE: Gi1/1/2
    NEIGHBOR: switch2.mydomain.com
    NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE: Te1/1/1
    PLATFORM: C9200L-48



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    neighbors:
    - CAPABILITY: R S I
      LOCAL_INTERFACE: Ten 1/1/1
      NEIGHBOR: switch1.mydomain.com
      NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE: Ten 1/0/4
      PLATFORM: C9500-16X
    - CAPABILITY: S I
      LOCAL_INTERFACE: Gig 1/1/2
      NEIGHBOR: switch2.mydomain.com
      NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE: Ten 1/1/1
      PLATFORM: C9200L-48

    lifc: "{{ neighbors |
              map(attribute='LOCAL_INTERFACE') |
              map('regex_replace', 'Ten ', 'Te') |
              map('regex_replace', 'Gig ', 'Gi') |
              map('community.general.dict_kv', 'LOCAL_INTERFACE') }}"
    nifc: "{{ neighbors |
              map(attribute='NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE') |
              map('regex_replace', 'Ten ', 'Te') |
              map('regex_replace', 'Gig ', 'Gi') |
              map('community.general.dict_kv', 'NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE') }}"

    update: "{{ lifc | zip(nifc) | map('combine') }}"
    result: "{{ neighbors | zip(update) | map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: lifc
    - debug:
        var: nifc
    - debug:
        var: update
    - debug:
        var: result



I marked the accepted answer, but I had actually moved forward using Jinja loops...
- name: PARSE NEIGHBORS
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    neighbors: "{{ neighbors_raw.stdout[0] | ansible.netcommon.parse_cli_textfsm('templates/cisco_ios_show_cdp_neighbors.textfsm') }}"

- name: TRANSFORM NEIGHBORS
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    neighbors: |
      {% for neighbor in neighbors %}
      {{ neighbor['LOCAL_INTERFACE'] | regex_replace('Ten ', 'Te') | regex_replace('Gig ', 'Gi') }}:
      {% for k, v in neighbor.items() %}
      {% if k == 'LOCAL_INTERFACE' or k == 'NEIGHBOR_INTERFACE' %}
        {{ k }}: {{ v | regex_replace('Ten ', 'Te') | regex_replace('Gig ', 'Gi') }}
      {% else %}
        {{ k }}: {{ v }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}

